# Convert a CSV/Excel file into and EXCEL file with formatting as table

Tags: python, excel, csv

***Context:***

I have a query that runs daily. I would like to email the query result data to stakeholders but I need it pre formatted for them as they may not have the skills required to format the data as a table. I have SSRS which is great for presenting the data but I still want the file emailed to them for filtering. I can generate CSV or Excel from the query and automate the email of the output but not without pre formatting the table first.

***Problem:***

I have a simple CSV/Excel file output from a query.

```
cust_id,cust_name
1,bishop
2,ripley
```

I want to convert this CSV/Excel output file, to a file that is pre-formatted as a sortable, filterable table with headers, and automate this process.

[Excel formatted table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9cKM.png)

Is this possible from python or some other server friendly code snippet? Either CSV >> Excel Formatted or Excel >> Excel Formatted. Both starting file types are fine in this instance.

***Limitation:***

I cannot install, update or import packages that are not part of stock python libraries.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `XlsxWriter`. Here is the documentaion: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: To read CSV/Excel files I would recommend using `pandas`, using either `pandas.read_csv()` or `pandas.read_excel()` according to the input.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with python but you can achieve this with VBA (not sure if that's an option for you). I would have an Excel file with VBA that would read the csv file, create a new excel workbook, format the data and then email it using VBA. But again, I'm not sure if that's an option for you?

Comment: Go with `XML`, this allows separate Data from Formatting. Package `xml` should be available in Standard Python Setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's xlsxwriter should have all the functionality you need.

Module page here: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html

Example for table formatting here http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial02.html

Example for adding auto filters here: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_autofilter.html

Upon reading the updated Limitations (can't install modules on the server), it's clear that using xlsxwriter without something like Anaconda is a no-go. Fallback solution unknown, I don't know of any module that comes with the standard python installation that does what you need.

Comment: And I would add this example for merging cells (as there are merged cells in OP's example): http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_merge1.html

Comment: Worth noting is that the module also supports pandas as data source so you might want to look into python pandas as possible way of importing and exporting data from your script: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: Thanks for your input. This seems like a suitable solution. However, I can only use stock py implementation as it sits on the server and I can't install any packages. I will update the question.

Comment: There are ways around that too. You could use something like Anaconda if you can't install python on the server for example because of permission issues. See https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs for the included packages and https://www.continuum.io/what-is-anaconda for assessing if it meets your needs.